# How to convert a sequence of bits (bitmask) into the corresponding hex number

Tags: linux, shell, binary, hex, initrd

Let's say I have the bitmask `1000000000`. I would like to convert it to its equivalent hexadecimal number, i.e. `0x200` (specifically, I only want the `200` part, but that's easy to take care of)

I know I can do this in Python or using various `bash` features and functions. Examples:

```
python -c "print format(0b1000000000, 'x')"
200

printf '%x\n' "$((2#1000000000))"
200

echo 'ibase=2;obase=10000;1000000000'|bc
200
```

But, I wanna do this using only functions available in `sh` (i.e. Shell, not Bash). More specifically, I want it to work with `sh` in an `initrd` image that I'm putting together. AFAIK, none of the examples above would work in an `initramfs` / `busybox` context.

Comment: so an `awk` solution is not usable for you? I'm almost certain you're going to have to call an external tool to do this conversion in `sh` Especially if you're talking about a `busybox` `sh`. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about `busybox` `sh`.  I can give `awk` a try. How would the conversion look like in this case? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems busybox sh has enough features ("substring" parameter substitution and arithmetic evaluation) to be useful enough for this:

```
$ busybox sh


BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

~ $ bitstr=1000000000
~ $ n=0
~ $ i=0
~ $ while [ $i -lt ${#bitstr} ]; do
> n=$(( 2*n + ${bitstr:$i:1} ))
> i=$((i+1))
> done
~ $ echo $n
512
~ $ printf "%x\n" $n
200
```

Encapsulate into a function:

```
b2h() {
  local bitstr=$1 n=0 i=0
  while [ $i -lt ${#bitstr} ]; do
    n=$(( 2*n + ${bitstr:$i:1} ))
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done
  printf "%x\n" "$n"
}
b2h 1000000000   # => 200
```

Comment: Turns out this works on my dev machine's busybox, but not in the embedded Linux device's `initramfs` where I want to do the conversion. Specifically, `n=$(( 2*n + ${bitstr:$i:1} ))` results in `syntax error: bad substitution`, which isn't too surprising since "string indexing is not POSIX standard" according to ShellCheck.

Comment: Is it still busybox on the device? What version?

Comment: `BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)`